# Best practices to get hierarchical PFUser information in iOS

Tags: ios, parse-platform

---

**I realize this question is a little bit subjective and likely to be closed, but Parse.com has specified StackOverflow as its current (only) support model. Please read the question before voting to close for ambiguity. I'm happy to edit the question to remove ambiguity, but I **do** believe this is the correct place to ask this question (given Parse.com's removal of their forums).**

---

I don't see my particular case covered in the Parse documentation, so I wanted to ask two things:

1. Am I doing this correctly?
2. Is there a better way? It seems like there must be.

I have an app with the following data structure:

**User** --> Items (Array of PFObject)

**Item** --> Category(Pointer to a PFObject)

**Category** 
Name (Property of Category) 
Description (Property of Category)

I'd like to run a query that returns the most recent information for the user, their items, and each item's category, returning the actual information at each level (including category name and description as `NSString` values), not just pointers that would need to be fetched.

I was originally accessing the `NSArray` pointer of the `PFUser` object and calling:

```
PFUser *currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];
NSArray *items      = currentUser[@"items"];
[PFObject fetchAllIfNeededInBackground:items block:^(NSArray *items, NSError *error) {
    // Do whatever
}
 ];
```

This method, however, prevented me (I think) from accessing the category property on each item (which is a pointer to another `PFObject`).

The way I am currently doing this is as follows:

```
PFUser *currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];
PFQuery *query      = [PFUser query];
[query whereKey:@"objectId" equalTo:currentUser.objectId];
[query includeKey:@"items.category"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *vaultItems, NSError *error) {
    if (error != nil) {
        // Handle error

    } else {
        // Got good data            

    }
}
 ];
```

I'm still working on fleshing out actual data into my design, but this appears to work ok and return available information without error.

This seems, however, like it can't possibly be the right way to do this. Can someone validate my code/approach or provide me with the standard way of doing this?

---

**UPDATE:**

Additionally, this method of running a query doesn't automatically update the stored local information for the current user (`[PFUser currentUser]`). So, basically, is there a way to refresh a single object, telling the server you want to populate certain sub-objects?

Comment: You can call `fetch` or `fetchInBackground:` to refresh an object, but you don't get to specify any includes (not sure if it includes pointers or not). Otherwise use `getObjectInBackgroundWithId:block:` to load a single object which does support includes.

Comment: @TimothyWalters I understand both of those options and how they work. What I'm trying to do, however, is (essentially) a `getObjectInBackgroundWithId:block:` call on `[PFUser currentUser]` that will **update the new data to `[PFUser currentUser]`** in the future. I'm trying to get around having to handle custom, separate storage of data that should be "store-able"/"refresh-able" on existing items. Make sense? I guess it just seems to me that I **should** be able to specify includes on a `fetch` call, at least on `PFUser` instances.

Answer (score 0):

You are able to use dot notation within your include statements, and this should bring in your second level. Does this help?

Comment: Sort of, but not really. I can get the list of a user's items, and get the sub-items using "include", but this doesn't actually populate to the [PFUser currentUser] object. So, I end up having to keep track of the current user's items in a separate area, which seems super odd to me. I'm looking for a way to refresh (fetch, get, I don't care) the current user and include sub-items, and THEN (this is the sticking point) have that information available in the [PFUser currentUser] object. Make sense? This seems like an odd omission to me.